# Yarn can't see resources and nodes

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to get a job to run on the Hadoop cluster but they are stuck in accepted. The problem is that, even if I have two nodes the resource manager cannot see it. In fact, in the web UI I don't see any resources nor nodes:

[image: screenshot]

Resource manager doesn't have any warnings or error in the log file and when I start a job it says this:

```
(base) ubuntu@myipaddress:~$ hadoop jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar  wordcount /user/ubuntu/wordcount/input /user/ubuntu/wordcount/output
2021-10-27 10:45:36,641 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at ipaddress/ipaddress:8032
2021-10-27 10:45:37,156 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/ubuntu/.staging/job_1635331527535_0001
2021-10-27 10:45:37,459 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2021-10-27 10:45:37,571 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2021-10-27 10:45:37,811 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1635331527535_0001
2021-10-27 10:45:37,811 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2021-10-27 10:45:38,014 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2021-10-27 10:45:38,014 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2021-10-27 10:45:38,518 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1635331527535_0001
2021-10-27 10:45:38,569 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-17-178:8088/proxy/application_1635331527535_0001/
2021-10-27 10:45:38,571 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1635331527535_0001
```

And then it is obviously stuck.

I thought that maybe my nodes weren't connected, but when I do `hdfs dfsadmin -report` everything is there and works normally.

I have no idea what to do, any clue? Thank you very much